# Отменить resize индикатора

Tags: android, resize, android-library

Имеется либа "CircleIndicator", которая способна показывать индикатор текущей страницы. Дело в том, что когда листаешь страницу во viewpager, то индикатор ресайзится и становится больше. Можно ли как-то отключить этот ресайз?

```
 <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            app:ci_drawable="@drawable/ic_circle_pager"
            app:ci_drawable_unselected="@drawable/ic_circle_pager_unselect"
            app:ci_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/pager"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете указать свою анимацию именения индикатора, в которой не будет изменения размера, а будет только изменение прозрачности. В папке `res/animator` создайте файл `indicator_anim.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="0.5"
        android:valueTo="1.0"/>

</set>
```

И укажите его в параметре `app:ci_animator`:

```
<me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:ci_drawable="@drawable/ic_circle_pager"
    app:ci_drawable_unselected="@drawable/ic_circle_pager_unselect"
    app:ci_margin="5dp"
    app:ci_animator="R.animator.indicator_anim.xml"
    android:layout_below="@id/pager"/>
```